# bootstrap popover over other popover

Tags: popover

I use bootstrap popover on my project. I open other popover because I want to compare values but all popovers are layering over other popovers. I add picture to show the problem. I want set dynamic popover position but I didn't do it.

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call 'hide' for all visible popovers e.g. on mouseleave event:

```
function hide_visible_popovers() {
  $('.popover:visible').each(function (index, value) {
    $(value).popover('hide');
  });
}

...
hide_visible_popovers();
// TODO show the expected popover
...
```